# Adding multiple products with attributes in woocommerce via url

Tags: woocommerce

Is there any way I can add to the cart multiple items with specific attributes for every one of them? I managed to add multiple items by their ID but some of them have attributes that I have to include as well.

An example (that I know it won't work in this form) would be https://www.cps.com.ro/cart?add-to-cart=9354&attribute=24,add-to-cart=9353&attribute=2. So I would need product 9354 with attribute 24 and product 9353 with attribute 2 to be added to the cart.

Any sort of help or guidance would be of great help.

Comment: Use grouped product ? No need of coding. After creating grouped product use yoursite.com/?add-to-cart=product_id

Answer (score 0):

You should try this (source: https://remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/):

```
your_domain/cart/?add-to-cart=PRODUCT_ID&variation_id=VARIATION_ID&attribute_pa_colour=ATTRIBUTE_SLUG
```

Comment: Those 2 articles are very useful but they show me only how to add multiple items to the cart. My need is to set up attributes also for those multiple items that I added to the cart.

Comment: @Rozovici: In the second article also mention the link "Add WooCommerce variable product with variations to cart" on the bottom, I think you should also read, the link is: https://remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/

Comment: It gives useful information when it comes to adding single items with different variations and attributes but no info on adding multiple items with multiple attributes.