# Get product color variable name and id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

so I got a working shortcode that outputs the selected product attribute name and id alongside, however, I have no idea how to obtain the same product variable name and id which is essentially from the same attribute.

This means that my current product form URL slug cannot add to cart the selected variable e.g. **( ?add-to-cart=18395&quantity=1&?variation_id=407 )** because the variation id is fetched from the attribute, and it is wrong I know.

```
add_shortcode ('color_attribute', function (){
    $color_attributes = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pa_pla_color', array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
    
    foreach ($color_attributes as $k => $color_attribute):
        if( $k > 0 ) echo "\n";
        echo $color_attribute->name . ' | ' . $color_attribute->term_id;
    endforeach;
} );
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I think you should check this URL, Mayu be it will helpful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138576/adding-multiple-products-with-attributes-in-woocommerce-via-url/69139898#69139898

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
add_shortcode ('color_attribute', function (){
    $color_attributes = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pa_pla_color', array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    echo $product->get_name();

    // Get Product Variations and Attributes
    $product->get_children(); // get variations
    $product->get_attributes();
    $product->get_default_attributes();
    $product->get_attribute( 'attributeid' ); //get specific attribute value

    foreach ($color_attributes as $k => $color_attribute):
        if( $k > 0 ) echo "\n";
        echo $color_attribute->name . ' | ' . $color_attribute->term_id;
    endforeach;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for similar solutions, this is how I achieved to solve my problem:

```
add_shortcode ('color_attribute', function (){
$color_attributes = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pa_pla_color', array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'asc',
    'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    if( $variation_ID > 0 ) echo "\n";
        // get variation ID
        $variation_ID = $variation->ID;
        $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );
        $variation_attribute = $product_variation->get_attribute('pa_pla_color');

    echo $variation_attribute . ' | ' . $variation_ID;

};
});
```